# Attach AdventureWorks Data to Existing Database (No Admin Role)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've been struggling to find a solution to this.

I have been provided with a database within a server run by our IT department.  I have full write access to that dB but no other rights on the server.

I'd like to use the AdventureWorks dB to learn SSIS, but obviously can't create the database from the .mdf file.

Is there another method I can use to create the relevant table and copy the AW data directly into my existing dB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know what's really funny? This is exactly the kind of thing SSIS is designed to do.

You're probably going to run SSIS on your own desktop or laptop as you learn. SSIS is part of SQL Server Developer Edition, so you can install that for free on your laptop. It also comes with the SQL Server engine, obviously.

So attach the AdventureWorks db to your local SQL Server Developer Edition, and then use SSIS to move the contents of the local tables you want over to the server run by your IT department.

Congratulations, you have your first ETL project! Bad news though: you're also the client. You're probably a terrible boss.

If you want to learn something easier, start by using SSIS to import the contents of a spreadsheet or a text file into that target SQL Server instead.

Comment: Thanks @Brent.  That's a great answer.  Downloading SQL Server Dev just now.  It looks like that will generally be a pretty good tool to have.